# When are the zeroes from Bezout's theorem real/rational/integral

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadratic-forms, nonlinear-system, intersection-theory, real-algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have $n$ quadratic homogeneous polynomials $f_1, \cdots, f_n$ in $n+1$ variables over the field $\mathbb{C}$. Bezout's theorem says that generically there will be $2^n$ common zeroes.

I was wondering if/when we could say something more about these zeroes. For example, is there some criteria we can give such that we can guarantee that at least one of the zeroes is actually in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (or say $\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$)?

Comment: You should either consider projective zeros or have as many polynomials as variables. In any case, what kind of an answer are you looking for when you have a single polynomial?

Comment: As an example of where this does work, consider the group law of an elliptic curve computed via the chord-tangent method.

Comment: @ronno I agree that by the way OP states the result and describes it as Bezout's theorem he must be considering projective zeros. I would also guess that OP wants the $ f_i $ to have indefinite signature as quadratic forms so that at least for $ n=1 $ a (projective) zero is guaranteed.

Comment: Yeah sorry I am considering it projectively. I guess we should assume the quadratic forms are isotropic?

Comment: If the $f_i$ have coefficients in some subfield $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$ then the zeroes have coefficients in a finite algebraic extension of $K$.